# He is {off/on/in/out} to Washington?

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the following is most appropriate to use?

He is {off/on/in/out} to Washington?

Comment: Normally it would be "off to Washington".  But there are particular contexts where the others might be used.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Essentially all of these choices can be correct in certain contexts, but you have not provided any. I strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how to use the site. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

He is **off** to Washington means he has left for Washington.

The rest are not colloquial. But *if* they were ever used . . .

"He is **on** to Washington" might mean "He is continuing his travels by going to Washington" or "He is on the phone to Washington."

"He is **in** to Washington" might mean "If Washington calls, tell them he's in."

"He is **out** to Washington" might mean "If Washington calls, tell them he's out."

Comment: He is out to Washington.  He's not in the office right now because he's in Washington.